# C how to determine how much memory a char** occupies

Tags: c, pointers, memory, heap-memory

The code below stores the filenames in a directory as a `char**` - called `files`. Ultimately, I need to store all of these filenames in just one `char*`. So the first thing I think that I logically need to do is find out how much memory these array of strings occupy and then allocate a `char*` of this size. I'm not very familiar with allocating from the heap techniques. How would one go about determining how much memory a `char**` occupies?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <malloc.h>

size_t file_list(const char *path, char ***ls) {
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t length = 0;
    DIR *dp = NULL;
    struct dirent *ep = NULL;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if(NULL == dp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no such directory: '%s'", path);
        return 0;
    }

    *ls = NULL;
    ep = readdir(dp);
    while(NULL != ep){
        count++;
        ep = readdir(dp);
    }

    rewinddir(dp);
    *ls = calloc(count, sizeof(char *));

    count = 0;
    ep = readdir(dp);
    while(NULL != ep){
        (*ls)[count++] = strdup(ep->d_name);
        ep = readdir(dp);
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char **files;
    size_t count;
    int i;

    count = file_list("/home/rgerganov", &files);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You `malloc()` a known number of bytes, so why don't you keep track of it? Also, don't use `calloc()` unless you are 100% sure you want to initialize *ALL* elements to 0 or, you **really** know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to get the size required for a memory zone pointed by a `malloc`ed pointer.

You need to manage and keep track of these sizes explicitly. A possible way is to have some `struct` containing them (or to keep that size elsewhere, or to recompute it). You could even end that `struct` with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

In all cases, you need *conventions* for this. Better explicit them, at least in comments.

BTW, [calloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) and [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) can fail (by returning `NULL`). You always should check that.

Answer (score 0):

You know how many filenames you have. You can use `strlen` to find the length of each string.  The actual minimum allocated length for a string is the strlen + 1, for the null terminator.  If you are planning to copy all the filenames to one long string, you will probably not want a null terminator at the end of each one (that won't be a single C-style string), but you probably will want some other kind of delimiter, whose length you will have to include.

So you would loop through the strings, summing up the lengths.  The length needed for each is the `strlen + <length of delimiter>` (possibly skipping the delimiter fro the very last string.